# How do I keep a 1:1 Scale of my page when I print

Tags: html, css, salesforce, responsive, visualforce

Its super annoying how the responsive style is functioning I've done plenty of research with different Height and Width Styling but non of them seem to do what I want. So now I think its just best to ask.

Is there any way of putting my Code into a container so that when I adjust screen size or print it will keep to a 1:1 Scale?

Here is how it looks on my monitor at full size- [Full Size Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9D4Xu.png)

Here is what the Print view looks like - [Print Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MM9Ea.png)

Can I wrap it in CSS or JavaScript to achieve this, and have a decent responsive system?

If so how?

Thanks for any and all help

Dan

Avoid this squishing - [Squished](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7DXN.png)

```
 <!--Apprentice Section -->
        <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-size_1-of-1 slds-box" Style="background: rgb(170,196,106);
           background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(170,196,106,1) 0%, rgba(161,213,79,1) 22%, rgba(128,194,23,1) 59%, rgba(170,204,120,1) 100%);
           background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(170,196,106,1) 0%,rgba(161,213,79,1) 22%,rgba(128,194,23,1) 59%,rgba(170,204,120,1) 100%);
           background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(170,196,106,1) 0%,rgba(161,213,79,1) 22%,rgba(128,194,23,1) 59%,rgba(170,204,120,1) 100%);
           filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#aac46a', endColorstr='#aacc78',GradientType=0 );">
           <div class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-p-around_small slds-size_1-of-1 slds-text-color_default" style="color:Black;">
              <b>Apprentice Section </b>
              <div class="slds-button slds-button_neutral">
                 <a href="#" onClick="MyWindow=window.open('{!Paperwork__c.Apprentice_Link__c}','MyWindow',width=600,height=300); return false;">
                    <div class="slds-text-body_small"> <b>Update Apprentice Section</b></div>
                 </a>
              </div>
           </div>
           <!--Head Row -->
           <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_shade slds-text-heading_medium " style= "background: rgb(179, 193, 172)">
              <span><b>DATA</b></span>
           </div>
           <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_shade slds-text-heading_medium" Style = "background: rgb(179, 193, 172)">
              <span><b>--</b></span>
           </div>
           <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-heading_medium slds-theme_shade" Style = "background: rgb(162, 174, 196)">
              <span><b>DATA</b></span>
           </div>
           <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-heading_medium slds-theme_shade" Style = "background: rgb(162, 174, 196)">
              <span><b>--</b></span>
           </div>
           <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_shade slds-text-heading_medium" Style = "background: rgb(179, 193, 172)">
              <span><b>DATA</b></span>
           </div>
           <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_shade slds-text-heading_medium" Style = "background: rgb(179, 193, 172)">
              <span><b>--</b></span>
           </div>
           <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-heading_medium slds-theme_shade" Style = "background: rgb(162, 174, 196)">
              <span><b>DATA</b></span>
           </div>
           <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-heading_medium slds-theme_shade" Style = "background: rgb(162, 174, 196)">
              <span><b>--</b></span>
           </div>
           <!--/Head Row -->
           <!--Row 1-->
           <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-size_1-of-1">
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-heading_small slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(179, 193, 172)">
                 <span><b>Apprentice Name</b></span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_shade " Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(179, 193, 172) ">
                 <span>
                    <apex:outputField Value="{! Paperwork__c.Ck_Apprentice_Name__c}"/>
                 </span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-heading_small slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(162, 174, 196)">
                 <span><b>Date of Birth</b></span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(162, 174, 196)">
                 <span>
                    <apex:outputField Value="{! Paperwork__c.Ck_Date_Of_Birth__c}"/>
                 </span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-heading_small slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(179, 193, 172)">
                 <span><b>Assessor</b></span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(179, 193, 172)">
                 <span>
                    <apex:outputField Value="{! Paperwork__c.Ck_Assessor__c}"/>
                 </span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-heading_small slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(162, 174, 196)">
                 <span><b>Competence APL</b></span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(162, 174, 196)">
                 <span>
                    <apex:outputField Value="{! Paperwork__c.Ck_Competence_Aim_to_Deliver__c}"/>
                 </span>
              </div>
           </div>
           <!--/Row 1-->
           <!--Row 2-->
           <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-size_1-of-1">
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-heading_small slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(179, 193, 172)">
                 <span><b>Competence Start Date</b></span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(179, 193, 172)">
                 <span>
                    <apex:outputField Value="{! Paperwork__c.Ck_Competence_Start_Date__c}"/>
                 </span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-heading_small slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(162, 174, 196)">
                 <span><b>Competence Expected End Date</b></span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(162, 174, 196)">
                 <span>
                    <apex:outputField Value="{! Paperwork__c.Ck_Competence_Expected_End_Date__c}"/>
                 </span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-heading_small slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(179, 193, 172)">
                 <span><b>Competence Component Title</b></span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(179, 193, 172)">
                 <span>
                    <apex:outputField Value="{! Paperwork__c.Ck_Competence_Title__c}"/>
                 </span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-heading_small slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(162, 174, 196)">
                 <span><b>Competence Delivery Location</b></span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(162, 174, 196)">
                 <span>
                    <apex:outputField Value="{! Paperwork__c.Ck_Competence_Delivery_Location__c}"/>
                 </span>
              </div>
           </div>
           <!--/Row 2-->
           <!--Row 3-->
           <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-size_1-of-1">
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-heading_small slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(179, 193, 172)">
                 <span><b>Competence Awarding Organisation</b></span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(179, 193, 172)">
                 <span>
                    <apex:outputField Value="{! Paperwork__c.Ck_Competence_Awarding_Organisation__c   }"/>
                 </span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-heading_small slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(162, 174, 196)">
                 <span><b>Competence Learning Aim Ref Aim</b></span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(162, 174, 196)">
                 <span>
                    <apex:outputField Value="{! Paperwork__c.Ck_Competence_Learning_Aim_Ref__c}"/>
                 </span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-heading_small slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(179, 193, 172)">
                 <span><b>Competence Level</b></span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(179, 193, 172)">
                 <span>
                    <apex:outputField Value="{! Paperwork__c.Ck_Competence_Level__c}"/>
                 </span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-heading_small slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(162, 174, 196)">
                 <span><b>Competence Tutor</b></span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(162, 174, 196)">
                 <span>
                    <apex:outputField Value="{! Paperwork__c.Ck_Competence_Tutor__c}"/>
                 </span>
              </div>
           </div>
           <!--/Row 3-->
           <!--Row 4-->
           <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-size_1-of-1">
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-heading_small slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(179, 193, 172)">
                 <span><b>Competence Title</b></span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_shade " Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(179, 193, 172)">
                 <span>
                    <apex:outputField Value="{! Paperwork__c.Ck_Competence_Title__c}"/>
                 </span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-heading_small slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(162, 174, 196)">
                 <span><b>Existing Employee</b></span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(162, 174, 196)">
                 <span>
                    <apex:outputField Value="{! Paperwork__c.Ck_Existing_Employee__c}"/>
                 </span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-heading_small slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(179, 193, 172)">
                 <span><b>Off The Job Training Hours Required</b></span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(179, 193, 172)">
                 <span>
                    <apex:outputField Value="{! Paperwork__c.Ck_Off_The_Job_Training_Hours_Required__c}"/>
                 </span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-heading_small slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(162, 174, 196)">
                 <span><b>Hours Worked Per Week</b></span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(162, 174, 196)">
                 <span>
                    <apex:outputField Value="{! Paperwork__c.Ck_Hours_Worked_Per_Week__c}"/>
                 </span>
              </div>
           </div>
           <!--/Row 4-->
           <!--Row 5-->
           <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-size_1-of-1">
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-heading_small slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(179, 193, 172)">
                 <span><b>Knowledge APL</b></span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(179, 193, 172)">
                 <span>
                    <apex:outputField Value="{! Paperwork__c.Ck_Knowledge_Aim_To_Deliver__c}"/>
                 </span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-heading_small slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(162, 174, 196)">
                 <span><b>Knowledge Start Date</b></span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(162, 174, 196)">
                 <span>
                    <apex:outputField Value="{! Paperwork__c.Ck_Knowledge_Start_Date__c}"/>
                 </span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-heading_small slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(179, 193, 172)">
                 <span><b>Knowledge Expected End Date</b></span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(179, 193, 172)">
                 <span>
                    <apex:outputField Value="{! Paperwork__c.Ck_Knowledge_Expected_End_Date__c}"/>
                 </span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-heading_small slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(162, 174, 196)">
                 <span><b>Knowledge Title</b></span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(162, 174, 196)">
                 <span>
                    <apex:outputField Value="{! Paperwork__c.Ck_Knowledge_Title__c}"/>
                 </span>
              </div>
           </div>
           <!--/Row 5-->
           <!--Row 6-->
           <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-size_1-of-1">
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-heading_small slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(179, 193, 172)">
                 <span><b>Knowledge Delivery Location</b></span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(179, 193, 172)">
                 <span>
                    <apex:outputField Value="{! Paperwork__c.Ck_Knowledge_Delivery_Location__c}"/>
                 </span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-heading_small slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(162, 174, 196)">
                 <span><b>Knowledge Awarding Organisation</b></span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(162, 174, 196)">
                 <span>
                    <apex:outputField Value="{! Paperwork__c.Ck_Knowledge_Awarding_Organisation__c}"/>
                 </span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-heading_small slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(179, 193, 172)">
                 <span><b>Knowledge Learning Aim Ref</b></span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(179, 193, 172)">
                 <span>
                    <apex:outputField Value="{! Paperwork__c.Ck_Knowledge_Learning_Aim_Ref__c}"/>
                 </span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-heading_small slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(162, 174, 196)">
                 <span><b>Knowledge level</b></span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(162, 174, 196)">
                 <span>
                    <apex:outputField Value="{! Paperwork__c.Ck_Knowledge_Level__c}"/>
                 </span>
              </div>
           </div>
           <!--/Row 6-->
           <!--Row 7-->
           <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-size_1-of-1">
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-heading_small slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(179, 193, 172)">
                 <span><b>Knowledge Tutor</b></span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12 slds-box slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-theme_shade" Style = "Height:100px; background: rgb(179, 193, 172)">
                 <span>
                    <apex:outputField Value="{! Paperwork__c.Ck_Knowledge_Tutor__c}"/>
                 </span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12  slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-heading_small" Style = "Height:100px">
                 <span><b></b></span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12  slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center" Style = "Height:100px">
                 <span>
                    <apex:outputText Value=""/>
                 </span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12  slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-heading_small" Style = "Height:100px">
                 <span><b></b></span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12  slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center" Style = "Height:100px">
                 <span>
                    <apex:outputText Value=""/>
                 </span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12 slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-heading_small" Style = "Height:100px">
                 <span>
                    <apex:outputText Value=""/>
                 </span>
              </div>
              <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12 slds-text-align_center slds-align_absolute-center" Style = "Height:100px">
                 <span>
                    <apex:outputText Value=""/>
                 </span>
              </div>
           </div>
           <!--/Row 7-->
        </div>
        <!--/Apprentice Section -->
```

Comment: It is best practice to always post code when asking a question.

Comment: There is so much I cant post all its just in general

Comment: It is hard for users to help you out when the question is very general such as "How do I do this?" There are many ways to do things so It is helpful to users when there is relevant code. Posting any code that is relative to this question is always recommended. You do not need to post EVERYTHING, just the code that is relevant.

Comment: You could make a page using cm as a unit type.

Comment: Adjusting to different screen sizes is what responsive web design is all about. 
 You don't need JS to do that, just use CSS and media queries.  You can even do a separate style sheet for printing, which won't even need to load unless being used for that purpose.